# sorting two vector array to get the cycles

Tags: sorting, octave

I'm trying get a sorting function that takes an array like the following:

```
0 2
1 5
2 3
3 0
4 1
5 4
```

and sorts it by cycles, i.e. it should output

```
0 2
2 3
3 0
1 5
5 4
4 1
```

Is there something build-in or how get this done in a lean way?

Comment: I dont understand what happens between those 2 matrices, can you explain?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions of [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab]. They are explicitly not the same. Only use both tags if you are asking about differences or similarities between the two. If you only use Octave, don't tag-spam [tag:matlab] along for the clicks please, as you'd force people to adapt their answers so that they work in both languages. Given people using MATLAB not necessarily know Octave exists whereas the other way around they do, I've removed the MATLAB tag.

Comment: @Ander the second is sorted in a sense that you can read the cycles en bloc: 0 2, 2 3, 3 0

Comment: @Adriaan ok, octave is fine with me...

Comment: @draks... are the elements on each column always unique, and if you not, what is the expected behaviour? And is the first column always sorted and if so, does it always start at zero and has increments of one, and if so, why have the first column at all?

Comment: @carandraug yes unique. Starts with zeros and increases. Think of it as predecessor and successor: start your walk with (0 2) then (2 3) and complete the cycle with (3 0). But you're right it is kind of redundant info, but without it your index book keeping gets more complex...

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
y=[]; %% results go here
k=1;
while length(x)>0 %% items left? loop 
    _x=x(k,:); %% local copy
    y=[y ; _x]; %% append
    x(k,:)=[]; %% remove from array
    try
        k=find(x(:,1)==_x(2)); %% find next
    catch
        k=1; %% no next? complete cycle, start over
    end     
end
```